# Enviar dados da aplicação para o Firebase - Delphi

Tags: delphi, firebase, mobile

Olá, estou com uma aplicação quase pronta. Porém ao final ela precisará colocar alguns dados em 2 TEdits como nome e e-mail, quando ela clicar no TButton quero que essas informações sejam gravadas no Firebase, que eu acho que é o melhor método para receber dados da aplicação. Mas não tenho conhecimento com firebase. Se tiver alguém que saiba por favor responder.. Darei agradecimentos no app!! Valeu

Comment: Você já deu uma olhada [aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/google-firebase-sdk-com-delphi-xe10/562069)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, você vai ter que consumir a API Rest do firebase, para que possa salvar/buscar esses dados.

Tem um projeto open source [Firebase4Delphi](https://github.com/spinettaro/Firebase4Delphi) que é uma biblioteca para consumir a REST API do firebase, tem alguns exemplos para você se basear no projeto do github e também nesse blog onde o cara que criou a biblioteca fez um tutorial [simple-chat-messaging-system-with-delphi-and-firebase](http://www.danielespinetti.it/2016/06/simple-chat-messaging-system-with.html), está em inglês, mas ainda é útil.